# Cómo puedo relacionar bien mis tablas en MySQL para un aplicación funcional?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Tengo tres tablas en mi BD,una llamada "clientes" con los siguientes campos:
(id,nombre_cliente, direcc_cliente, telef_cliente, email_cliente)

Otra tabla llamada "trabajos" con los campos
(id, codigo,nombre, costo), los cuales muestro en  las siguientes tablas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y al hacer click en mi `tabla1` en el boton verde "AGREGAR TRABAJO", sale una ventana modal que guarda los datos en la tabla "pedidos" con los campos(id_pedido, id_cliente, nombre_cliente, fecha_ingreso, Cantidad,Anticipo)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo la siguiente consulta, que al escribir un nombre me aparece su info:

```html
<? 
include("config.php");
 //Instaciamos la clase de base de datos
  $db = new Clasedb();
  //Llamamos a la funcion para conectar a la base de datos
  $db->MySQL();
  //Consultamos la tabla regis
  $consulta = $db->consulta("SELECT P.id_pedido, P.nombre_cliente, P.Fecha_ingreso, P.NombreTrabajo, T.nombre, T.costo, P.Cantidad, P.Cantidad*T.Costo AS Total, P.Anticipo, P.Cantidad*T.Costo-P.Anticipo AS Resta  FROM pedidos AS P JOIN trabajos AS T ON P.NombreTrabajo = T.id WHERE P.nombre_cliente  LIKE '%$buscar%'");

?>
```

Y como resultado me aparece lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi duda es, ¿esta bien la forma de hacerlo? ¿están bien relacionados los datos?
o ¿cómo se asigna informacion a un determinado cliente a través de su id? y otra cosa, ¿cómo guardo esa consulta en una tabla? Es que si me dan un nuevo anticipo quiero ingresarlo y que este se actualice en la tabla y en la BD? y quiero agregarle un input select que diga estatus: pagado/pendiente y que en una tabla salga los que estan pendientes y otra los que ya pagaron para que al final pueda mostar una tabla de las ventas que hay cada mes o de los doctores activos algo asi.

Answer (score 1):

Buenas Rms,

Por lo que comentas yo veo que estás creando varias entidades/tablas de 1 a n que cruzan sus datos.

En estos casos existe una entidad derivada de estas dos.

El ejemplo seria algo parecido a esto:
[image: Relacion con tabla derivada]

Si te das cuenta la relación existente entre la entidad 1 y la 2 provocará la creación de otra tabla para poder persistir está información.

Una vez se tiene claro el hecho de que hay que crear esta tabla, hay que tener en cuenta la dependencia de la E3 con respecto a E1 y a E2. Es decir que pasaría si eliminamos un registro en E1 o E2.

Pueden haber casos en los que debas crear una constraint con opciones de ON DELETE CASCADE  para E1 o para E2 para no provocar registros huérfanos.

Espero haberte ayudado, y no vas por mal camino un saludo.